# AWS AppConfig and Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, aws-app-config

Can I use AppConfig to update 50+ parameters in parameter store in different AWS accounts?

If so, how? I looked at the instructions and was trying to figure out how to do this, but there isn't much out there. I want to create the name and value pairs in either yml or json for the app configuration and profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppConfig` is **not used for updating SSM parameter store** values in different accounts. It is used by your application, e.g. on ec2 or in container, to fetch latest config data. This is useful when you want to manager configuration of your application in one central location and your app is running in many environments.

The source of the configurations that `AppConfig` delivers to your application can be SSM Parameter Store (PS), among others.

Comment: Got it. Thought I would be able to use it as a deployment method for managing ssm name and value pairs in a pipeline, but doesn't look like it. Back to the drawing board.